# Tradingview strategy alert works without any position

Tags: pine-script, alert, tradingview-api

The code below helps me to enter long positions with the conditions I defined.

The code triggers alerts to open and close long positions on the exchange I am using.

However, the code sometimes triggers alerts even if there is an open position or not.

In particular, "shortside" conditions can randomly be met and can trigger the second alert which I try to prevent if there is no open position.

It would be appreciated if you could help me to figure this out.

```
//@version=4
strategy("ABC", initial_capital=100, currency="USD", default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=100, pyramiding=0, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.1, process_orders_on_close=true)


// Define the input variables
smaPeriod = input(title="SMA Short", type=input.integer, defval=30)
smaPeriodLong = input(title="SMA Long", type=input.integer, defval = 220)
vwapPeriod = input(title="VWAP Period", type=input.integer, defval=14)
stopLossPct = input(title="Stop Loss %", type=input.float, defval=2.0)
ma_length = input(title="Vol. SMA Short", type=input.integer, defval=30)
ma_length_long = input(title="Vol. SMA Long", type=input.integer, defval=220)
volume_multiplier = input(title="Volume Multiplier", type=input.float, defval=1.0)
rsi_length = input(14, "RSI Length")
rsi_sma_length = input(30, "RSI SMA Length")

// Calculate the indicators
sma = sma(close, smaPeriod)
sma_long=sma(close, smaPeriodLong)
vwap = vwma(close, vwapPeriod)

ma_volume = sma(volume, ma_length)
volume_1 = volume[1]
ma_volume_1= sma(volume[1], ma_length)
ma_volume_long= sma(volume, ma_length_long)

rsi_value = rsi(close, rsi_length)
sma_value = sma(rsi_value, rsi_sma_length)

// Define the long condition
long_condition = rsi_value > sma_value * 1.1

// Define the price conditions
aboveVWAP = close > vwap
aboveSMA = close > sma
aboveSMA_Long = close > sma_long

// Define the volume conditions
volume_condition_1 = volume * volume_multiplier > ma_volume * 1.3
volume_condition_2 =  volume_1 > ma_volume_1 * 1.3
volume_condition_3 = volume > ma_volume_long * 1.3

// Define the stop loss level
stopLoss = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stopLossPct/100)

// Open a long position if conditions are true
longside = long_condition and volume_condition_1 and volume_condition_2 and volume_condition_3 and aboveSMA_Long and aboveSMA and aboveVWAP

// Close the long position if conditions are true
shortside = crossunder(close, sma) and crossunder(close, vwap) or close < stopLoss

if longside
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    alert(XXXXX)
     
if shortside
    strategy.close("Long")
    alert(XXXXX)
```

I tried "shortside" conditions to prevent unwanted triggers but could not find a right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use strategy.opentrades to know if a position is open or not :

```
if shortside and strategy.opentrades > 0
```

see : [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_strategy{dot}opentrades](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_strategy%7Bdot%7Dopentrades)